# How to use use custom Vue plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins

I created a Vue plugin to activate console.logs if a user sets a property in localStorage. The plugin is a wrapper around console.log(). If the user enters 'localStorage.isLoggingData = true', then the plugin will test if that property exists in local storage and the logData function with run

index.js

```
import logData from '../plugins/logData

  // I want to console.log this inital data coming into the app
  async init ({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await messaging.send(ACTION.READY)
      logData(data)
```

main.js

```
import logData from '../plugins/logData

// Use logData to optionally view console.log statements
Vue.use(logData)
```

logData.js

```
export default {
  install: function (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$logData = function (dataToLog) {
      const isLoggingData = localStorage.getItem('isLoggingData')
      if (isLoggingData) {
        console.log(dataToLog)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently when we have an application error we route to an error page,  when I comment out the 'logData(data)' I am routed to the correct page in my app. Am I not creating the plugin or importing it correctly?

Update

**index.spec.js**

```
import logData from '../plugins/logger'
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import App from '@src/App'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.use(logData)

const mocks = {
  _vm: {}
}
mocks._vm.$logData = logData

const wrapper = shallowMount(App, {
  mocks,
  localVue
})
```

I am now told to mock _vm. Is this the correct way to mock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `init({ state, commit, dispatch })` function looks like it comes from `vuex`.
You can't access vue methods from vuex actions directly.

You could directly export your `logData` function in `index.js` and import that in vuex:

index.js

```
import { logData } from '../plugins/logData';

// I want to console.log this inital data coming into the app
async init ({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
  try {
    const { data } = await messaging.send(ACTION.READY);
    logData(data);
    // ...
  } catch(e) { /* ... */ }
}
```

main.js

```
import logDataPlugin from '../plugins/logData';

// Use logData to optionally view console.log statements
Vue.use(logDataPlugin);
```

logData.js

```
export function logData(dataToLog) {
  const isLoggingData = localStorage.getItem('isLoggingData');
  if (isLoggingData)
    console.log(dataToLog);
}

export default {
  install: function (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$logData = logData;
  }
}
```

If you want to have the method only as a vue plugin and not expose it directly you could pass the vue instance to your vuex action to access `$logData`:

```
// in your vuex actions:
const actions = {
  async init ({ state, commit, dispatch }, {vm}) {
    vm.$logData("Hello");
  }
};

// call action from vue component:
export default {
   mounted() {
     // pass reference to vue instance to vuex store
     this.init({vm: this});
   },
   methods: {
     ...mapActions(['init'])
   }
}
```

Comment: The main question I have now, is why we can't access Vue methods, if written on the prototype, in Vuex actions?

Comment: @KevinT. `vue` and `vuex` are two different libraries, you can only access methods defined on the `Vue.prototype` inside vue components. You can however pass your current vue component to the `vuex` action (my last example), and then use the `$logData` method you defined on the prototype on that instance

Comment: My PR reviewer wants me to call, `this._vm.$logData(data)` in the init action. I have that working. Now, I don't understand how to access / call `this._vm.$logData()` in my tests. I also have other tests that are failing now because "Cannot read property '_vm' of undefined. It seems `this` is not accessible.

Comment: @KevinT. I would strongy discourage using `this._vm` - the underscore before the property name is a convention to signal this a private member. `this._vm` is nowhere documented in the official `vuex` documentation, so you should not rely on it to be a reference to the calling vue component - this might change in future `vuex` versions. I would recommend directly exporting the function like shown in my example above. This will also make testing easier.

Comment: @KevinT. If you still want to do it via your vue plugin, you can pass the vue instance as an extra parameter to your vuex action or use one of the work-arounds shown in [this github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1399).
You could also check out [`vuex-persist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist) which will store all (or part of) your vuex store in `localStorage` so you don't have to deal directly with it.

Comment: I'm now told to mock `_vm` in index.spec.js  See additional edits above in code